Unwanted height expansion on Flutter when using Image widget on Row
When using an Image widget inside a Expanded + IntrinsicHeight, a weird behavior occours when the width size changes, making the Expanded expands in height direction even in a Row. I don't know how to explain it, but the code only works when setting a height, or removing the Expanded, which is not the behavior I would like.
When the available width size is small, it has the correct behavior.
Normal way
When expanded the available width size, it occours a unexpected behavior, expanding the Image height:
Height expansion
Code example (can be run in dartpad.dev, paste the code, run, and resize the width):
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() => runApp(
      MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold(
          body: Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: IntrinsicHeight(
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    // Works when not using Expanded here
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.redAccent,
                          child: Image.network(
                            'https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C560BAQEu7AUSpfr2MQ/company-logo_200_200/0/1630622338041?e=2147483647&v=beta&t=TxFY6Qj5NDdhP8NIKQBgX0_NojCFunfkMb73BB_GgiY',
                            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
//                             height: 250, // Works if uncomment
                          ),
                        ),
                        const Spacer(),
                        const Text('TEXT'),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      height: 300,
                      color: Colors.amberAccent,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

I tried some different scenarios (like adding a height size, removing the Expanded or the IntrinsicHeight), but none of them gave me the behavior I would like: not expanding the height unnecessarily, but the "TEXT" keeping aligned with the bottom of the right component (the yellow one).

If your blue and yellow part are equally divided then try below code...
body: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  // Image Section
                  IntrinsicHeight(
                    child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                      child: Image.network(
                        'https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C560BAQEu7AUSpfr2MQ/company-logo_200_200/0/1630622338041?e=2147483647&v=beta&t=TxFY6Qj5NDdhP8NIKQBgX0_NojCFunfkMb73BB_GgiY',
                        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                        fit: BoxFit.contain,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Spacer(),
                  Text("text"),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(flex: 1, child: Container(color: Colors.yellow))
        ],
      ),

